# An error occurred during local report processing(excelrender).The row item structure object corresponding to a line cannot be Null

Tags: c#, reporting-services, ssrs-2008-r2

[image]
I used SSRS report.I tried to export report to excel I got this error.Please can you help me.

Comment: Some more background is needed, what were you doing when you got this error? Were you exporting to excel?

Comment: Answer might be in here. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20189803/the-row-item-structure-object-corresponding-to-a-line-cannot-be-null

Comment: Yes,I tried to export excel I got this error.I tried to export PDF and Word these are working fine

Comment: I tried, stackoverflow.com/questions/20189803/… this but did not working

Comment: https://refactorsaurusrex.com/post/2014/localprocessingexception-rendering-localreport-to-excel/

Comment: Should be your exact problem